# Wso2 IOT Error 500

Tags: wso2, centos7, iot

I'm new to WSO2. I folllowed all steps from the wso website to install WSO2 IOT.
After I attempt login to devicemgt I get the following error[Error 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QiZ5.png)

I'm using Centos 7.2 with java and maven installed.

These are the logs:

```
ERROR TargetHandler I/O error: Host name verification failed for host : 172.20.0.222
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Host name verification failed for host : 172.20.0.222
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.ClientSSLSetupHandler.verify(ClientSSLSetupHandler.java:171)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:308)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.outboundTransport(SSLIOSession.java:451)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.outputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:152)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.writable(BaseIOReactor.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:342)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2017-07-04 15:43:25,176 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-89]  WARN EndpointContext Endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://{uri.var.hostname}:{uri.var.portnum}/api-application-registration will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
2017-07-04 15:43:25,176 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-89]  WARN EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : AnonymousEndpoint with address https://{uri.var.hostname}:{uri.var.portnum}/api-application-registration - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Tue Jul 04 15:43:55 EEST 2017
2017-07-04 15:43:25,176 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-89] ERROR JsonUtil #toXml. Could not convert JSON Stream to XML. Cannot handle JSON input. Error>>> null
2017-07-04 15:43:25,177 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-89] ERROR DeferredMessageBuilder Error building message
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not convert JSON Stream to XML. Cannot handle JSON input.
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.toXml(JsonUtil.java:298)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonBuilder.processDocument(JsonBuilder.java:35)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:148)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:140)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:83)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:203)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:214)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:53)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.invokeNextFaultHandler(AbstractEndpoint.java:691)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.onFault(AbstractEndpoint.java:530)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.onFault(HTTPEndpoint.java:66)
        at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:101)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:285)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetErrorHandler$1.run(TargetErrorHandler.java:139)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:245)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.<init>(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:66)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getReader(JsonUtil.java:333)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getReader(JsonUtil.java:315)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.toXml(JsonUtil.java:294)
        ... 29 more
2017-07-04 15:43:25,178 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-89] ERROR RelayUtils Error while building Passthrough stream
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not convert JSON Stream to XML. Cannot handle JSON input.
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.toXml(JsonUtil.java:298)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonBuilder.processDocument(JsonBuilder.java:35)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:148)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:136)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:140)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:83)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:203)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:214)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:53)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.invokeNextFaultHandler(AbstractEndpoint.java:691)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.onFault(AbstractEndpoint.java:530)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.onFault(HTTPEndpoint.java:66)
        at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:101)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:285)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetErrorHandler$1.run(TargetErrorHandler.java:139)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:245)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.<init>(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:66)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getReader(JsonUtil.java:333)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getReader(JsonUtil.java:315)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.toXml(JsonUtil.java:294)
        ... 29 more
2017-07-04 15:43:25,179 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-89] ERROR AnonymousListMediator Error while building message
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:283)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:142)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:140)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:83)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:203)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:214)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:53)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.invokeNextFaultHandler(AbstractEndpoint.java:691)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.onFault(AbstractEndpoint.java:530)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.onFault(HTTPEndpoint.java:66)
        at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:101)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:285)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetErrorHandler$1.run(TargetErrorHandler.java:139)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not convert JSON Stream to XML. Cannot handle JSON input.
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.toXml(JsonUtil.java:298)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonBuilder.processDocument(JsonBuilder.java:35)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:148)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:136)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:245)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.<init>(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:66)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getReader(JsonUtil.java:333)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getReader(JsonUtil.java:315)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.toXml(JsonUtil.java:294)
        ... 29 more
2017-07-04 15:43:25,181 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-89] ERROR _WSO2APIRegistrationApplication_ Error while building message
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while building Passthrough stream
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.handleException(RelayUtils.java:283)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:142)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:99)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:140)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:83)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AnonymousListMediator.mediate(AnonymousListMediator.java:37)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:203)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:214)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorFaultHandler.onFault(MediatorFaultHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:53)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.invokeNextFaultHandler(AbstractEndpoint.java:691)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.onFault(AbstractEndpoint.java:530)
        at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.HTTPEndpoint.onFault(HTTPEndpoint.java:66)
        at org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler.handleFault(FaultHandler.java:101)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:285)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetErrorHandler$1.run(TargetErrorHandler.java:139)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not convert JSON Stream to XML. Cannot handle JSON input.
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.toXml(JsonUtil.java:298)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonBuilder.processDocument(JsonBuilder.java:35)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:148)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.builldMessage(RelayUtils.java:136)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.initialize(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:245)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.<init>(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:66)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(JsonXMLInputFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getReader(JsonUtil.java:333)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.getReader(JsonUtil.java:315)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.toXml(JsonUtil.java:294)
        ... 29 more
2017-07-04 15:43:25,220 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-17] ERROR js {/app/modules/oauth/token-handler-utils.js} Error in retrieving tenant based client application credentials from API Manager - getTenantBasedClientAppCredentials(x, y)
2017-07-04 15:43:25,221 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-17] ERROR auth-module An exception thrown when executing the script '/app/modules/login.js'.
2017-07-04 15:43:25,221 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-17] ERROR auth-module {/app/modules/oauth/token-handlers.js} Could not set up encoded tenant based client credentials to session context as the server is unable to obtain such credentials - setUpEncodedTenantBasedClientAppCredentials(x)
2017-07-04 15:43:26,045 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-91]  WARN APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Missing Credentials
2017-07-04 15:43:26,047 [-] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-93]  WARN APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Missing Credentials
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, [WSO2 IoT 3.1.0](http://wso2.com/iot/) has been released, and it has fixed all of those issues. The reason for the issue is that default pack runs on the localhost URL. And SSL certificates are configured with the localhost. Therefore if you need to run the WSO2 IoT 3.1.0 on IP, you will have to change the configurations in few places.

But with the WSO2 IoT 3.1.0, we have included a "change-ip.sh" script in [WSO2IoT-3.1.0]/scripts/ folder. If you run this script, you will be able to configure the product to IP based URLs.

Answer (score -1):

These errors are still showing up in 3.3.0

You need to update the install instructions and/or provide a proper installation script. Currently WSO2IOT is not ready for production.